# Не сканируются пакеты в Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Начал изучать Spring, столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Пометил нужные классы аннотацией `@Component`, далее выбрал аннотацию `@ComponentScan` и выбрал папку для сканирования, где находится нужный класс, но выдаёт ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExceptio

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам `@ComponentScan`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На англоязычных ресурсах писали, что возможно надо перенести `Main` выше по папкам, но это не помогло. По разному пробовал указывать наименование пакетов для сканирования, но все время выдаёт ошибку и всегда подсвечивает красным.

Answer (score 2):

Высвечивает ошибку потому, что пакета `example` нет в проекте. В аннотации `@ComponentScan( basePackage="org.example")`

Можно даже без аргументов указывать `@ComponentScan` так как сканирование происходит от текущего пакета.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.